# How does this statement test for memory alignment

Tags: c, memory-management

I am writing a hobby OS, using several guides. Page aligning memory is a recurring theme. Several guides test if a certain address is page aligned by using the following statement:

```
if (address & 0xFFFFF000) // if true the address is not page aligned
```

I don't get how that tests for page alignment. If I take a non-paged aligned (4k pages) address, f.e. `0x12345678` and `AND` that with `0xFFFFF000` on my calculator I get `0x12345000`. That is non-zero so the `if`-statement is `true`.

However, if i take an aligned address, f.e. `0x12345000` and perform the same calculation I (obviously) get `0x12345000` as well.

So how is this statement testing for page-alignment?

Edit:

For example this guide uses this test at several points: http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html

Comment: Can you mention the guides that show this as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is this statement testing for page-alignment?

It does not. In order for it to perform the check it needs to be changed to either

```
if (address != (address & 0xFFFFF000)) // Not page-aligned
```

or

```
if (address & ~0xFFFFF000) // Not page-aligned
```